# facebook api authentification returns invalid key hash after user sign up

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, parse-platform, ionic3, angular5

I am trying to use facebook api to allow the user to authentificate using social network.
During the first authentification which is also the registration of the user in parse  everything goes well.
Then if the user tries to authentificate again, it retruns

```
    Invalid key hash.the key has ...... does not match any stores key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at developers.facebook.com/apps/.....
```

And her is the code source.

```
      getUserDetail(result) {
//alert("id" + result.authResponse.userID + " access_token" + result.authResponse.accessToken + " expiration_date" + result.authResponse.expiresIn)
var facebookAuthData = {
  "id": result.authResponse.userID,
  "access_token": result.authResponse.accessToken,
  "expiration_date": result.authResponse.expiresIn
};
var navCtlr = this.nav;

this.fb.api("/" + result.authResponse.userID + "/?fields=id,email,name,first_name,last_name,picture,gender,birthday", ["public_profile"])
  .then(res => {
    var navCtlr = this.nav;

    Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(facebookAuthData, {
      success: function (user) {
        //alert("success")
        if (!user.existed()) {
          user = {
            "email": res.email,
            "name": res.name,
            "firstname": res.first_name,
            "lastname": res.last_name,
            "sexe": res.gender,
            "birthday": res.birthday,
            "image": res.picture.data.url,
            "UserParse": user,
            "userID": user.id

          };
          //  alert("user ok")
          if (res.gender == "male") {
            user.sexe = "Homme"
          }
          else {
            user.sexe = "Femme";
          }

          navCtlr.push(SignupPage, { user: user, pageId: 1 });
        } else {
          navCtlr.setRoot('MenuPage');
        }
      },
      error: function (error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);

      }
    });
  })
  .catch(e => {
    alert(e.toString())
    console.log(e);
    alert("getuserErreur" + e)
  });
  }

 facebookconnect() {

this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email'])
  .then(res => {
    if (res.status === "connected") {

      this.isLoggedIn = true;
      //alert("good" + res.toString())
      this.getUserDetail(res);
    } else {
      alert("bad" + res.toString())
      this.isLoggedIn = false;
    }
  }).catch(e => alert(JSON.stringify(e)));
```

Comment: And did you configure the key hashes in facebook developer?

Comment: how can i configure key hashes in facebook developer?

Answer (score 0):

Use the java sdk keytool to generate a key hash for your app (on android) as described here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | PATH_TO_OPENSSL_LIBRARY\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | PATH_TO_OPENSSL_LIBRARY\bin\openssl base64
```

This should end in a key hash that you have to copy to the facebook developer console: Settings-> General-> Add Platform -> Android
[image]